# How to solve Use of unresolved identifier 'SetOptions'?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have updated Firestore to follows. Now, I can't use it anymore. I removed, reinstalled several times. But there is no change. I am losing my mind. The issue is:

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'SetOptions'".

```
db.collection("").document("").setData([ "p1answered":false, "p1OutofTime": false ], options: SetOptions.merge())

Bolts (1.9.0)
Using BoringSSL (10.0.2)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.33.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.33.0)
Using Firebase (5.0.1)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.0.1)
Using FirebaseFirestore (0.12.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.0.0)
Using FirebaseUI (5.0.0)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.6)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.15)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.31.0)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
Using Protobuf (3.5.0)
Using SwiftySound (1.0.0)
Using TwitterCore (3.1.0)
Using TwitterKit (3.3.0)
Using gRPC (1.12.0)
Using gRPC-Core (1.12.0)
Using gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.12.0)
Using gRPC-RxLibrary (1.12.0)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

//Pod File

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Tahmin Et' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

```
 # Pods for My App

    pod 'SwiftySound'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is okay, you just need to `import FirebaseFirestore` in your class.

**Edit: After discussion**

`pod 'FirebaseFirestore'` is also not correct. It should be `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`. Have a look at [Firebase getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) choose iOS tab under **Set up your development environment**.

**Edit: 2**

In latest documentation it is like:

```
db.collection("cities").document("BJ").setData([ "capital": true ], merge: true)
```

Comment: I already did it. Actually the app was working before updating the pods. I am going to give up to learn swift. Everyday, I have new problem without a solution.

Comment: Giving up anything is not a good thinking. Be a man and trust yourself. (y)

Comment: It was working. Now it is not working. I was trying to say is not about to import FirebaseFirestore.

Comment: import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

import SwiftySound

class SettingsScene: SKScene {

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Tahmin Et' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Tahmin Et

    pod 'SwiftySound'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'

end

Comment: Your pod seems wrong it should be `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`

Comment: I fixed and reinstalled. I am still getting same issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171604/discussion-between-thetiger-and-tom-b).